# syntax colors on ipython

Tags: bash, ipython, ubuntu-16.04

This is bugged me for several days and what I've found so far on the internet do not satisfy me.

I've installed `ipython` on two separate ubuntu boxes. The ipython prompt is different on each of the boxes.

I'm reaching the boxes through `ssh` via a Windows bash emulator, `Cmder`

This box where the config is closest to ok e.g it gives me syntax color when typing a string or else.

[image]

This is the box where the config is not what I want

[image]

Reading articles and questions, it seems that I need to add the line below in the file `.bashrc` in my linux account to be able to have syntax colors in `ipython`

```
export LS_COLORS = "no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=00;35:bd=40;33;01:ex =00;36"
```

I did it but it still gives me the same grey outlook in my second box and worse, when I type a `ls` command in my linux box, I have this error

> ls: cannot analyse the value of the environment variable LS_COLORS

Any ideas on what should I do to get color syntaxes for `ipython`?

Comment: What is this _λ Cmder_ thing?

Comment: hi @gniourf_gniourf, its bash emulator for windows. I don't think it is related to that thingy. The displayed should be homogenous although I checked on the ubuntu box where lies the issue and the color syntax appears correctly.

Comment: Then I guess it's the terminal emulator that's the culprit. By the way, I've tried `ipython` after unsetting `LS_COLORS` and the colors appear just fine. I doubt `ipython` uses this environmental variable at all.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I tried with other boxes, especially one I setup on Digital Ocean and I have color syntaxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recent versions of IPython use Prompt_toolkit, which provide colors via Pygments. YOu need to pass an option to IPython to select the "theme", you'll the following.

If You issue `ipython --help`

```
--colors=<CaselessStrEnum> (InteractiveShell.colors)
  Default: 'Neutral'
  Choices: ['Neutral', 'NoColor', 'LightBG', 'Linux']
  Set the color scheme (NoColor, Neutral, Linux, or LightBG).
```

meaning you can either pass the `--colors` flag or set the `c.InteractiveShell.colors=...` in your config.

You will also find the following option if you issue a `In[1]: %config TerminalInteractiveShell`:

```
TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style=<Union>
    Current: 'legacy'
    The name or class of a Pygments style to use for syntax highlighting. To see
    available styles, run `pygmentize -L styles`.
```

That controls the theme highlighting of IPython. (use `--TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style=...` at the prompt , or set `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style-...` in a config file).

Keep in ind the the escape control sequences used to show color may not be compatible with all terminal emulators, and that some part of IPython (in particular tracebacks) do not respect the themes (yes we know and we are planning to fix that at some point but it's quite a bit of code to refactor).

Keep in mind also that there are 2 types of colors with ANSI code. "True color" that is to say you tell the terminal emulator the R,G,B values of a character, and "short colors". Where you tell the terminal emulator that the color of the character is one of 8 predefined colors. These 8 predefined colors depends on the terminal emulator itself and can sometime be changed from the terminal emulator preferences. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3/4_bit) for example of changes in colors.

Comment: Merci bcp @Matt

Comment: Pas de problème !

Comment: Thanks Matt .. then "...or set the c.InteractiveShell.colors=... in your config"...
Talking about Windows here, where and what is that file ??

Comment: Answering myself : the config file should be in (and be named with extension .py)
c:\Users\<yourUserId>\.ipython\profile_default\startup

Comment: Use `ipython profile create` to create a configure file, and then you can set up your ipython color schemes. [Ref here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/config.html).